# How to expand Designer View with ScrollViewer in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, grid, visual-studio-2013, scrollviewer

I am adding more content than the Designer View sees in Visual Studio 2013 for Windows Phone 8. I added ScrollViewer within the Grid to be scrollable but it doesn't scroll neither does designer view and I cannot see the content but only see highlights of my content and move them about invisibility without seeing exactly where I would like it to be positioned. The last three buttons I put are not seen in designer view because the view is cut off from seeing it.

So, I would like a solution as to how I can work with the designer view that expands content larger than designer view on a single page?

Secondly, the ScrollViewer is not visible when applied to the Grid. Any solutions to make it work?

Thanks!

XAML Code Focus:

```
    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock Text="JP APPS" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="&lt;Data Query&gt;" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Height="1000" Width="Auto">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock x:Name="firstNameTBL" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="First Name:" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="firstNameTB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="72" Margin="0,42,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="253"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="lastNameTBL" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,119,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Last Name:" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="lastNameTB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="72" Margin="0,151,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="253"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="emailAddressTBL" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,228,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Email Address:" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="emailAddressTB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="72" Margin="0,260,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="253"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="dateOfBirthTBL" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,337,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Date Of Birth:" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <toolkit:DatePicker HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="dateOfBirthPicker" ValueChanged="dateOfBirthPicker_ValueChanged" Margin="0,370,0,0"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,447,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Gender:" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <RadioButton Content="Male" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,479,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <RadioButton Content="Female" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="113,479,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <TextBlock Name="fingerprint" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,551,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Fingerprint:" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <Button Content="SCAN HERE" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,583,232,208" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <Button Content="Submit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="154,0,0,136" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
            <Button Content="Reset All" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,131" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Full XAML Code:

```
<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock Text="JP APPS" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="&lt;Data Query&gt;" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <!--Height of the Grid has to be greater than the ScrollViewer's Height to make it scrollable.-->
    <!--Removing the ScrollViewer's Height enables you to see the entire page in a transparent-like view-->
    <ScrollViewer Height="605" Width="480" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,-390" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid MinHeight="605" Height="1000">
            <TextBlock x:Name="firstNameTBL" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="First Name:" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="firstNameTB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="72" Margin="0,42,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="253"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="lastNameTBL" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,119,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Last Name:" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="lastNameTB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="72" Margin="0,151,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="253"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="emailAddressTBL" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,228,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Email Address:" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="emailAddressTB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="72" Margin="0,260,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="253"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="dateOfBirthTBL" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,337,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Date Of Birth:" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <toolkit:DatePicker HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="dateOfBirthPicker" ValueChanged="dateOfBirthPicker_ValueChanged" Margin="0,370,0,0"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,447,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Gender:" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <RadioButton Content="Male" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,479,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <RadioButton Content="Female" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="113,479,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <TextBlock Name="fingerprint" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,551,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Fingerprint:" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <Button Content="SCAN HERE" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,420,250,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="250"/>
            <Button Content="Submit" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,250,94" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
            <Button Content="Reset All" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="235,0,10,94" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Up at the top of your view where your namespaces are declared, do you see something that says d:DesignHeight and/or d:DesignWidth? If so strip those out. As for your scrollviewer stuff, show the containing parent so we see everything. Oh, and how you have the children of that Grid contained in the ScrollViewer with all these crazy margins is atrocious, in fact all your layout is. We should work on your layout too. :)

Comment: No, I don't see d:DesignHeight or d:DesignWidth in the code anywhere in XAML. Should I go ahead and set it? Also, about the layout thing, I'm not sure if I understand what you mean by the margins being atrocious? What is wrong with it and what is right way or efficient way to do it?

Comment: Ya sorry I conveyed that a little harshly after a rough morning. The idea overall though is it isn't generally a good idea to rely on positioning objects in the designer and relying exclusively on alignments and margins to keep your layout because you'll run into discrepancies with various devices that way as well as end up with some bloated code base that can be tedious to navigate. I'll have some free time in a couple hours and I'll give you an example with what you've posted. As for the d:DesignHeight/Width, ya give it a shot. d:DesignHeight="1000" for example.

Comment: Okay, thanks for tip! I got both problems fixed. Here's how: Height of the Grid has to be greater than the ScrollViewer's Height to make it scrollable. Removing the ScrollViewer's Height enables you to see the entire page in a transparent-like view and position them. Full Code is updated! However, I would like to know how to avoid discrepancies with different devices. A link or more info on this would be great. Thanks!